# Android VOIP Application

Tags: android, voip

Am working on an android voip application which is using SIP protocol.But still am not sure on how Watsapp or Skype is opening app on incoming call. Exactly what is triggering app to open. I don't want to use a never ending service or any third party sdk to achieve this behaviour.Anyone have idea on how this magic is happening from a base level of understanding.

Comment: On the app foreground as the SIP register then you can get the call while it goes to a background or killed state then can get [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=CjwKCAiArJjvBRACEiwA-Wiqq6vWS8R72JPXN7KvejgjnToSQY2Kcw6-dltbft1z52hdzUjJwYhhCRoCa2wQAvD_BwE) then after can register the SIP and get the call

Comment: Mainly you have two options for this:

1. First, use android default API SIP protocol 
[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip]

or 
2. Third-party sdk :Linphone

Comment: andrido default SIP package is having some limitation and is difficult to use in advance VOIP applications

Answer (score 0):

There is two part for calling:

1 - voip server : like astrisk freePBX and more

2 - voip client : like Skype, Zioper and more

The Architect is clear :

every user can register in voip server and call together (clients) with RTC protocol

Comment: am using pjsip library